# feeding chatbot with a question and answer excel file amazon lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I have all the description of many different products in an excel file and I want the chatbot to respond to the user according to the input of the user. The chatbot should be able to catch some keywords from the queries and search for the most suitable answer from the file. Do I have to use Amazon Kendra for this or is there any other way? I will be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find that in this instance Kendra would be easier to work with and would likely provide you with better results than Lex straight out the box.

If you choose to solely use Lex for this, you will need to spend a fair amount of time designing the various intents needed and possibly also a set of Lambda functions to support your Lex bot.

Whereas with Kendra, you simply supply the data for Kendra to ingest and within minutes you have a very powerful search capability. The best part is that you can integrate Kendra into Lex.

The biggest issue will be the cost factor as Kendra is very expensive.

[Integrating Amazon Lex with Kendra](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/integrate-amazon-kendra-and-amazon-lex-using-a-search-intent/)